# Regular expression to delete square brackets in MS Word

Tags: regex, ms-word

I have an MS Word document full of references in square brackets in a format like this – *Lorem ipsum* [1] *dolor sit amet* [2], *consectetur adipiscing elit* [3]. ... *Proin eu auctor lectus* [99].

I'd like to delete all of those, probably using regular expression, but square brackets have a special meaning in MS Word's regexp. I tried [ \[ (0-9){1,} \] ] but it does not produce what I'm expecting.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

I just tried this one in Word 2010 with your example text and this worked for me:

```
(\[[0-9]*\])
```

It searches for a open square bracket `\[`, followed by numbers `[0-9]*` and a closing square bracket `\]`, brackets escaped by a `\`

See [office help](https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/Find-and-replace-text-by-using-regular-expressions-Advanced-eeaa03b0-e9f3-4921-b1e8-85b0ad1c427f) for more detailed information about regex in word.

Comment: Or `\[[0-9]@\]`. Works.